# Regex to to detect white spaces, new lines to count words in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I m trying to do count words in Summernote editor in angular.
I have created a service to count words but its not working for new lines

this is the sample text

```
Hult International 23

s

e

r

t
```

I have tried to do it in the following way

```
if (text && text.length > 0) {
    text = text.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '').replace(/&amp;nbsp;/g, '').replace(/&nbsp;/g, '').trim();
    return text.length ? text.split(/\s+/).length : 0;
}
```

u can see it in the attached image too http://i.prntscr.com/rVnabSWbR1G5rcelz915qQ.png

Answer (score 2):

```
String.prototype.countWords = function(){
    return this.split(/\s+\b/).length;
}
```

[Now you can use `text.countWords()`](https://jsfiddle.net/dolomike/gyosjqgk/) and there's no need to use the replace functions.

Comment: I have applied this solution but its not working no change in output

Comment: I added a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dolomike/gyosjqgk/) to my answer as an example. It appears to work as expected and is a relatively simple solution. I tested it with your example input as well.

Comment: yes your solution is working in jquery and JS but its not working for me in angularJS. thanks for the time and help

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't anticipate angular making a difference here. I wonder why that is the case? Either way, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing `\n` with an empty string, thus removing all whitespace between lines and making a single word from `23sert`.
I'm not sure I understand the point of the `replace` step, but if you don't have non-words symbols in your text you could just  use
`return text && text.length ? text.split(/\s+/gm).length : 0`
instead of your whole block.

(Might need some polishing to account for leading/trailing spaces)

Comment: Your solution didn't work, but it gave me a hint to solve it, thanks for the help and time

Answer (score 1):

after thoroughly investigation of regex structure, I replaced a white space while replacing tags & it worked

```
text = text.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, ' ').replace(/&amp;nbsp;/g, '').replace(/&nbsp;/g, '').trim();
```

posting this answer may be it helps some one else

Answer (score 0):

this should do it

```
theText.split(/\b[a-zA-Z]/g).length;
```

[image]